# 301 Redirect with complete url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have domian domain1.com and 2nd domain2.com i cpanel.
domain1.com is main domain
domain2.com is addon domain

So domain1.com and domain2.com are in same account.

I tried redirect 301 /free www.domain2.com/free

But it gives be error because .htaccess of domain1.com i also applicable to domain2.com

What i require is when some one try to open domain1.com/free they need to automatically redirect to domain2.com/free .
How can i achieve it, If they are both under same account.

Is is possible to use complete url in 310 redirect or is there any other way.I tried a lot of codes from internet none works.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EDmSYhzv here is my complete htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If both domains are on same server, you need to use mode-rewrite instead of mod-alias to redirect domaiA to domainB

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^free http://www.domainB.com/free [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, Its not working for me.Here is my complete .htaccess http://pastebin.com/EDmSYhzv

Comment: My site is not www and its the link is like this. https://domain1.com/account/upgrades

Comment: I found some online generator it worked for me. May be this helps to some other people. https://donatstudios.com/RewriteRule_Generator